# Ruby easy way to assign fixed value if a regex dont match?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
author = m.match(/Author: (\w*)/)[1].strip
```

it sometimes throw me a "undefined method []" exception

What is the best way to assign a fixed value (for example "" or "not found") if the regex dont match? maybe rescue?

Comment: The `strip` call is redundant, since `\w*` won’t ever capture anything that `strip` would remove.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is:

```
author = m[/regex/, 1] || "not found"
```

Ruby is really incredible.

Comment: Thanks Arnold; not a day passes without me learning smth awesome and fresh in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

```
def find_author s
  s =~ /Author: (\w*)/ ? $1 : 'not found'
end

find_author 'Author: Joe' # => "Joe"
find_author 'No author here' # => "not found"
```

Comment: How is called the =~ operator?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I call it "regex match operator"? :)

Comment: @ArnoldRoa I believe the pickaxe calls it a “pattern match operator”, along with `!~`.